# UI rendering inconsistencies in Flex application

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, air, flash

Has anyone noticed UI rendering inconsistencies within Flex applications. I am having issues with radio buttons and text controls inside a repeater. Below is a sample...

What would cause such inconsistencies? Computer performance, internet speed?

The repeater below has an XML web service acting as a data provider, using Flex's e4x support. Is there a threshold of data that can be rendered in a given Flex app?

Note that *most* of the time Flex renders the app ok, but *most* of the time is not good enough in this application.

Thanks.

[alt text http://img87.imageshack.us/img87/1435/error3b.jpg](http://img87.imageshack.us/img87/1435/error3b.jpg)

MXML Code below, as requested:

```
<mx:Repeater id="rpQuestions" width="100%" height="100%" dataProvider="{srv.lastResult..Question}">
    <mx:Box backgroundColor="#FFFF99" width="100%">
        <mx:Text styleName="questionText" text ="{rpQuestions.currentIndex+1 +': ' +rpQuestions.currentItem.@QuestionText}" fontSize ="12" width="100%" selectable="false" />
    </mx:Box>
    <mx:HBox visible="{rpQuestions.currentItem..Image.length() > 0}" includeInLayout="{rpQuestions.currentItem..Image.length() > 0}">
    <mx:Repeater id="rpImages" dataProvider=quot;{rpQuestions.currentItem..Image}" >
        <mx:Image source="{rpImages.currentItem.@Path}" width="350" height="250"  />
    </mx:Repeater>
    </mx:HBox>
    <mx:Repeater id="rpAnswers" dataProvider="{rpQuestions.currentItem..Answer}" width="75%" height="75%">
        <mx:HBox>
            <mx:Spacer width="12" />
            <!-- NOTE: the RadioButton's label property is not used because long text won't  wrap. Instead we use a Text control. -->
            <mx:RadioButton 
            groupName="{rpQuestions.currentItem.@QuestionID}"
            value="{rpAnswers.currentItem.@AnswerID}"
            click="_questionAnswerd(event)"
            selected="{rpAnswers.currentItem.@Selected == '1'}"
                        />
        <mx:Text text="{rpAnswers.currentItem.@Answer}" width="600" selectable="false"  />
        <!-- End-->
        </mx:HBox>
    </mx:Repeater>
</mx:Repeater>
```

Comment: Just edited question to include the mxml.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to make sure that the hbox's inside the repeaters have a percentage set for the height (say 100% for the one with the radio buttons, its repeater which is set to 75%).

Or you could try to invalidate the display/size after the repeaters have finished creating the subcomponents ('repeatEnd' event).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's related to a reported bug in the Flex SDK 3.3.0:

[SDK-198805: Nested Repeater components do not display correctly when there is an intermediate component](https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-19805)